# How to make UITableView transparent in IOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, transparent

I have tried many times and many method to UITableView  transparent in IOS7,but it still does not work.I have no any ideas...

```
"[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];"


UIView* bgv = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundView:bgv];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(247.0/255.0)
                                 green:(151.0/255.0)  blue:(121.0/255.0) alpha:.3];
```

All over these 3 method I've tried,still not work.

Can anybody give some more tips about this problem?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: You're creating a view and making that clear. You're not making your self.tableView clear. bgv is not linked to anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your need to set your tableView's background to clear color, you need a reference to your table view.

Answer (score 16):

Use this

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to just clear your `TableView` cell color. And select tableview background color from property list. Or set tblobj.backgroundcolor...

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

set table view background color clear and backgound view nil

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

set cell background color as clear color and cell contentview background color as clear

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This will gives you transparent tableView

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting the `TableViewController` class `backgroundColor` to `clearColor` programmatically did the trick.

You just need to make sure every single object with a background should have the transparent color. And while I set all of them to transparent in the interface builder, it apparently doesn't always take.

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting table view background color to clear color, you need to set cell.contentview background color to clear color